# Swing in Investment Banking

Tags: java, swing, banking

Why is Swing used so predominantly in Investment Banking's view layer? Very few IBs venture out to the newer technologies? What are the pros/reasons?

Comment: Legacy can be an answer to such question... And Swing works well, there is no reason to run and ditch it.

Comment: They cant afford to play with new things when *money* is involved. They always play with old, widely used and trusted technologies to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

Having never worked in an investment bank this is a pure guess, but Most of the backend systems will be written as either Java EE or Spring based java services. If the UI is for internal use only then it doesn't make sense to employ a team of UI developers with different skills when they have the java developers can do the work.